# Only stores last input? Tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I want the user to type in the amount of sold tickets for every cinema. However it is only the last input that is stored in my variable "sålda". How can I fix this?

```
def part_of_function():

        bio1 = []

      
        i = 0
        for elements in BIOGRAFVAL:
            vuxen = StringVar()
            pensionär = StringVar()
            barn = StringVar()

            
            Label(fönster4, text= BIOGRAFVAL[i]).pack()
            Label(fönster4, text="Skriv in antal biljetter av varje sort du vill köpa").pack()
            Label(fönster4, text="Max antal platser för " + BIOGRAFVAL[i] + " är " + str(PLATSER[i])).pack()

            
            personer = [('vuxen',vuxen),('pensionär', pensionär), ('barn',barn)]
            
            for p in personer:
                sålda = välj_biograf(fönster4, p[0] + "biljett", p[1]) #välj_biograf is called*
                sålda.pack()
            i += 1

        Button(fönster4, text="fortsätt", command=lambda: info()).pack()
   


        def info(): 
            fönster5=Tk()
            fönster5.title("Biljettförsäljning för EN biograf.")
            fönster5.geometry("350x200")

            bio1.append(sålda.get())
            print(bio1)  #here is only the last element printed 


            """ *code for the function "välj_biograf" that is called
            def välj_biograf(fönster, person_typ, text_variabel):
            Label(fönster, text=person_typ).pack()
            sålda = Entry(fönster, textvariable=text_variabel)
            sålda.pack()
            return sålda """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bio1` is a local variable inside the `part_of_function` function. The value of it will be lost each time the function ends and reset back to a blank list again next time the function is called.

Create the `bio1` empty list outside the function (to make it global) and then use `global bio` inside your function so that the global variable is modified.

Also note that you should only ever have one instance of `Tk()` inside your code. I suspect that in your code you have more than one. If you want a new window, use `Toplevel()` instead

As pointed out by CoolCloud, you need to use .get on the values of `personer`/`p`

```
sålda = välj_biograf(fönster4, p[0] + "biljett", p[1].get())
```

Element 1 of the tuple `p` is a StringVar so you need to use `.get()` to get it's value.

Comment: Also you could mention they have to use `get()` on the `StringVar()` to get its value here ~ `('vuxen',vuxen),('pensionär', pensionär), ('barn',barn)`

Comment: @CoolCloud vuxen=StringVar().get() ? or in personer = [('vuxen',vuxen.get()),('pensionär', pensionär.get()), ('barn',barn.get())]?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It still only returns the last value though. What should I write in my function info(): to print all inputs?

Comment: @scotty3785 I suppose the values are stored somewhere since there are entry-boxes for all expected values(?)

Comment: @CoolCloud do you know?

Comment: @Ella At this point, its hard to say without you providing the entire code we can run and check.

Comment: @Ella Maybe post a new question?